# UIPicker not selectable while UI Testing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to create a test for a flow in my app that includes two UIPickerView and I'm unable to select them while running in the "record" mode of Xcode. Also if I check the count of datePickers, pickers or pickerWheels I always get back 0. Any idea of what can be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I find [Joe Masilotti's stuff](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet#interacting-with-pickers) to be indispensible when UI Testing.

Like he says you can do:

```
app.pickerWheels.element.adjust(toPickerWheelValue: "Picker Wheel Item Title")
```

Don't bother yourself doing this in Record mode. Only use that to get a general idea and quickly do stuff. As soon as things get complicated and you want to get serious, you shouldn't use it anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Thing is that it doesn't work, I have two UIPicker but this is just not making any difference.